# Require JS Install issues with Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, requirejs

I'm trying to get this running within my app

https://github.com/biggora/express-useragent

I have node / npm installed and have installed the module via the guidelines. I see the module within the "node_modules" file.

However, I noted within the code of express-useragent that requirejs is needed after spotting require().

Headed over to the requirejs site and installed via npm successfully. However, I don't understand how to get this running - the documentation is not clear on how to add or "use" require js within my app.

Please see attached for the folder structure if that helps and here is my package.json file - I note that require js is not added under "express-useragent:

[image]

```
[![{
  "name": "blockadblock",
  "version": "3.2.0",
  "description": "Detects ad blockers (AdBlock, ...)",
  "author": {
    "name": "Valentin Allaire",
    "email": "valentin.allaire@sitexw.fr",
    "url": "http://sitexw.fr/"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "keywords": \[
    "adblock",
    "advertising",
    "ad",
    "block",
    "lock",
    "detection",
    "detecting"
  \],
  "main": "blockadblock.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/sitexw/BlockAdBlock",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/sitexw/BlockAdBlock.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/sitexw/BlockAdBlock/issues"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express-useragent": "^0.2.4"
  }
}][1]][1]
```

I don't understand where I'm going wrong and can't find many tutorials out there to guide people on installing / using require js via node.

Comment: It is not clear at all what you are asking here. It looks like you decided to install RequireJS because of the use of a `require` call in the code but `require` is built into Node.js. Moreover `express-useragent` is a middleware for `express` and as such I'd expect it to be used server-side, where RequireJS *can* be used but is *usually* not used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require()` is built in to node and can just be used (the same way you would just use `console.log()`.

I would suggest that you remove requireJS from your project while you remember to prevent any confusion further down the line (`npm uninstall requirejs --save` assuming you installed it using npm).

Comment: Thanks for this info mate. I removed require from the project using npm uninstall. The issue I'm getting now when trying to use require is I get the error: "ReferenceError: require is not defined" which lead me on the path to installing require. I'm unsure what's going on here.